# Magento 2 : How to Process Order Returns to Store Credit Manually?

Tags: magento2, orders, store-credit, returns

How to process order returns to Store Credit
using ?

1. order_number
2. product_sku
3. return_qty

Any thoughts how this can be achieved ?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: any thoughts on this?